# How to find task user is currently working upon?

Tags: activiti

I have following usecase:

A user is working on a user task, and meanwhile other tasks are assigned to her.
So now multiple tasks are assigned  to the user.

User logs out of the system, and logs in. System needs to determine which of the assigned task user was working upon last time.

How can it be done?

There are date fields in act_ru_task table, like claim time, create time etc which can be used to make this decision.

But is there any other facility within Activiti API to do it?

Answer (score 0):

No, Activiti cannot (and should not) maintain recent activities for user.\

These sort of customization can be maintained in user sessions/ browser caches without loading the engine.